# FZF not finding dirs

Tags: terminal, fzf

I have a `~/GitHub dir`, which I can locate with `find GitHub`. I have a default installation of `fzf`, which uses `find`. When I run `fzf` on the home dir, fzf doesn't find `GitHub` dir.

If I pipe so: `find GitHub | fzf` it shows the dir in the results.

What gives?

Comment: What do you get if you do `echo $FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND`?

Comment: I didn't set it. Its default value is nil.

Comment: Does fzf ran from your home directory find all the other directories? and only 'skips' the directory called 'Github'?

Comment: Run from home dir, it skips some other dirs, too. Setting $FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND to use `ag' so: export FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND='ag --hidden --ignore .git -l -g ""' fixes the issue.

Comment: @user3156459, did you figure out what the problem was?

Comment: @PRouleau no, I didn't